# Mac terminal, is it possible to create a folder of folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, mkdir

I'd like to create a folder `ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools` under my home directory. But I don't want to create it fold by fold. Could I make it with only 1 command?

```
(base) xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro /home % pwd
/home
(base) xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro /home % ls
(base) xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro /home % 
(base) xxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro /home % mkdir -p ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools
mkdir: ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools: Operation not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's `mkdir -p`

```
mkdir -p ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools
```

From `man mkdir`:

> -p
> Create intermediate folders as required.  If this option is
> not specified, the full path prefix of each operand must already
> exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no error
> will be reported if a directory given as an operand already
> exists.

Comment: Yea, I read the manual and try `mkdir -p ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools`. But this doesn't work. It hints `mkdir: ubuntu/airflow/dags/survey_tools: Operation not supported`

Comment: OK, that probably means you're trying to create this in a folder that the terminal process does not have access to, e.g. your desktop. Some of them can be granted, others I'm not so sure. Where specifically are you trying to run this? mkdir -p works fine from my home directory.

Comment: (Other possibilities are file permission problems or if one of the paths existed as a file you'd get different errors for that.)

Comment: Would you like to look at the question again? I added more details in it. As to the premission, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ah OK - I thought you meant your user's home folder (which is under /Users), not /home itself. I'm not sure, sorry: the first time I tried to access it in Terminal I did get a "Would you like to grant permission" pop-up, but if you didn't choose yes I'm not sure how to get that back. You could always use sudo or su to try this as root.